# Modeling an American Call Option in R

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I am trying to model an American Call Option in R using the Binomial Tree Approach. I already have the code for the European Call Option using the Binomial Approach and I would like to know how I can adjust my code to check in every step whether it is optimal to exercise early or not. The code for the European Call Option is shown below;

```
q_prob = function(r, delta_t, sigma) {
  u = exp(sigma*sqrt(delta_t))
  d = exp(-sigma*sqrt(delta_t))

  return((exp(r*delta_t) - d)/(u-d))
}

build_stock_tree = function(S, sigma, delta_t, div_yield , T ,N) {
  tree = matrix(0, nrow=N+1, ncol=N+1)

  u = exp(sigma*sqrt(delta_t))
  d = exp(-sigma*sqrt(delta_t))

  for (i in 1:(N+1)) {
    for (j in 1:i) {
      tree[i,j] = S * u^(j-1) * d^((i-1)-(j-1)) * exp(-div_yield * delta_t *N)
    }
  }
  return(tree)
}

value_binomial_option = function(tree, sigma, delta_t, r, X, type) {
  q = q_prob(r, delta_t, sigma)
  option_tree = matrix(0, nrow=nrow(tree), ncol=ncol(tree))
  if(type == 'put') {
    option_tree[nrow(option_tree),] = pmax(X - tree[nrow(tree),], 0)
  } else {
    option_tree[nrow(option_tree),] = pmax(tree[nrow(tree),] - X, 0)
  }
  for (i in (nrow(tree)-1):1) {
    for(j in 1:i) {
      option_tree[i, j] = ((1-q)*option_tree[i+1,j] + q*option_tree[i+1,j+1])/exp(r*delta_t)#change here for American Option
    }
  }
  return(option_tree)
}

stock=

binomial_option = function(type, sigma, T, r, X, S, div_yield , N) {
  q = q_prob(r=r, delta_t=T/N, sigma=sigma)
  tree = build_stock_tree(S=S, sigma=sigma, delta_t=T/N, div_yield = div_yield, N=N)
  option = value_binomial_option(tree, sigma=sigma, delta_t=T/N, r=r, X=X, type=type)
  delta = (option[2,2]-option[2,1])/(tree[2,2]-tree[2,1])
  return(list(q=q, stock=tree, option=option, price=option[1,1], delta=delta))
}

delta = function(binomial_option, row, col) {
  stock_tree = binomial_option$stock
  option_tree = binomial_option$option
  return((option_tree[row+1, col+1] - option_tree[row+1, col])/(stock_tree[row+1, col+1] - stock_tree[row+1, col]))
}


binomial_option(type='call', sigma=0.2, T=3, r=0.1, X=100, S=150, div_yield = 0.05, N=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already identified the line at which you need to check whether exercise is optimal or not. The calculation you're currently doing at this line is the payoff of holding the option for `delta_t` more time.

<strike>You've also already calculated the intrinsic value of the option for each stock price state `j` when you populated the boundary nodes of the mesh, i.e. `option_tree[nrow(option_tree),j]`. Recall the intrinsic value of the option is the payoff of exercising the option now.</strike>

Thus all the hard work is already done. In order to reflect the payoff of making the optimal decision between holding or exercising at time `i`, you just have to replace the line

```
      option_tree[i, j] = ((1-q)*option_tree[i+1,j] + q*option_tree[i+1,j+1])/exp(r*delta_t)#change here for American Option
```

With

```
      exercise.payoff <- option_tree[nrow(option_tree),j]
      hold.payoff <- ((1-q)*option_tree[i+1,j] + q*option_tree[i+1,j+1]) / exp(r*delta_t)
      option_tree[i, j] <- max(exercise.payoff, hold.payoff)
```

Bottom-up dynamic programming is really that elegant.

Note you don't need to discount the exercise payoff since it will occur at time `i`, unlike the hold payoff which occurs at time `i+1`.

---

EDIT: my earlier remark about `exercise.payoff` already being calculated is only correct for the trinomial tree model. Since you're using a binomial tree, you actually have to compute `exercise.payoff` on every iteration with

```
      exercise.payoff <- if(type == 'put') max(X - tree[i,j], 0) else max(tree[i,j] - X, 0)
```

Furthermore, there's an error in your `build_stock_tree()` function that was making it hard for me to generate a case where the American call price was more valuable than the corresponding European call price. In particular, you need to raise the "discount" factor of `exp(-div_yield * delta_t)` to the `(i-1)`th rather than to the `N`th power, i.e.

```
      tree[i,j] = S * u^(j-1) * d^((i-1)-(j-1)) * exp(-div_yield * delta_t *(i - 1))
```

The `i = 1` period is today, so there should be no dividend compounding at all in `tree[1,1]`. On every period thereafter, the stock should decrease in value by the same factor due to dividend payout.

---

EDIT 2: this is a nitpicky thing that is unrelated to the question, but you should use more idiomatic vectorized operations in R when you can. It's impossible to vectorize the outer loop in `value_binomial_option()` since it involves dynamic programming, but you can easily vectorize the inner loops. I would accomplish it with

```
build_stock_tree <- function(S, sigma, delta_t, div_yield, T, N) {
  tree <- matrix(0, nrow = N + 1, ncol = N + 1)

  u <- exp(+sigma * sqrt(delta_t))
  d <- exp(-sigma * sqrt(delta_t))

  for (i in 1:(N + 1)) {
    j <- 1:i
    tree[i, j] <- S * u ^ (j - 1) * d ^ ((i - 1) - (j - 1)) * exp(-div_yield * delta_t * (i - 1))
  }
  tree
}

value_binomial_option <- function(tree, sigma, delta_t, r, X, type) {
  q <- q_prob(r, delta_t, sigma)
  option_tree <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(tree), ncol = ncol(tree))
  option_tree[nrow(option_tree), ] <- if (type == 'put') pmax(X - tree[nrow(tree), ], 0) else pmax(tree[nrow(tree), ] - X, 0)
  for (i in (nrow(tree) - 1):1) {
    j <- 1:i
    exercise.payoff <- if (type == 'put') pmax(X - tree[i, j], 0) else pmax(tree[i, j] - X, 0)
    hold.payoff <- ((1 - q) * option_tree[i + 1, j] + q * option_tree[i + 1, j + 1]) / exp(r * delta_t)
    option_tree[i, j] <- pmax(exercise.payoff, hold.payoff)
  }
  option_tree
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin Jin. However I have realised that I did not incorporate dividend yield in the calculation of my probabilities and I have adjusted it as follows; 'q_prob = function(r, delta_t, sigma, div_yield) {
  u = exp(sigma*sqrt(delta_t))
  d = exp(-sigma*sqrt(delta_t))
  
  return((exp((r-div_yield)*delta_t) - d)/(u-d))
}
'. I have also adjusted this accordingly in other following codes but the result that I am getting does not look good comparable to my side calculation. Did I adjust this correctly?

Comment: I now want to adjust the correct code to value a derivative which starts off as a European Call Option for the first 2 years and finishes off as an American Call Option for the last 2 years.The best way to do this, is using a binomial tree by first treat the last 2 years as a standard American option, working from the maturity date (4 years) to the 2 year date, and checking in every step whether it is optimal to exercise early or not. From then on continue backwards to today but now you no longer take American but European steps. How do I adjust that code to value such a derivative